# Tutorials and Materials for RESTful webservices with NetBeans

Tags: web-services, netbeans

Where can I find tutoriols for RESTful webservices creation using netbeans IDE.

And I want to learn from the basics of RESTful services, and how it is advanced from RPC or SOAP based webservices. Please, Is there any reliable resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with this tutorial from Netbeans and found it a good starting point:

[Getting Started with RESTful Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

Answer (score 0):

A good netbeans-based video tutorial, that focuses on the basics of RESTful webservices towards the end, can be found here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBNaiVWwAZw

You'll find the section on RESTful webservice from about 34minutes in.